# Powershell script not logging as expected when run from command line

Tags: windows, powershell, task-scheduler

I have a simple powershell script that opens a ur and logs whether it was successful:

```
$LogFile = ".\userLoad.log"
$Date = Get-Date
Try
{
    $Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://dxscrumassist.zhi.com/maintenance/loadusers.aspx")
    $Response = $Request.GetResponse()
    $LogString = "$Date - User Load Success"
    $Response.Close()
}
Catch
{
    $LogString = "$Date - User Load Failure"
}
Add-content $LogFile -value $LogString
```

When I run the program from PowerShell ISE it works fine and logs as expected:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\AAA\loadUsers.ps1
```

When I run the exact same file from the Windows command line I am not getting a log file entry. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What folder are you trying to run it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the thing, you're telling powershell to write to ".\log.log" and it is.  It's just I don't think it's writing where you expect it to be.  It's writing to where `get-location` is, which is actually a default that's usually your user directory (or that of the account executing it).  Check `.\users\<username>\log.log` and see if it's there.  Now, what you want is a way to get the current script execution directory and write your output there.  You can do this like so:

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory
{
  $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
  Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}
$ScriptDir = Get-ScriptDirectory
```

In your case, `$LogFile` would actually be:

```
$LogFile = "$ScriptDir\log.log"
```

Check out `Invoke-WebRequest` :)  You might find it easier for web requests.  You might also want to consider adding a `finally` to your `try\catch` so that it's a `try\catch\finally`.  The `finally` block always runs and you can use it to log script execution (in this instance).

Answer (score 3):

My suspicion is that it is a working directory issue. Look in C:\Windows\System32 and see if your log is there. Or give and explicit path to where you want the log rather than using a relative path.

Comment: I agree with you about the working directory, but I think it's probably defaulting to the user directory or root.  +1